# How to create a custom dialog title in android?

Tags: android, dialog, customdialog

How to access the title of the dialog to change the typeface font ( to create a custom title of dialog) ?

Comment: Is it necessary to change existing title style (I don't know if that's possible)? But could you create totally custom dialog layout containing custom title instead and hide default title altogether?

Comment: how to hide the default title ???

Comment: ``Dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)``. Alternatively you could do some searching on ``FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE``, there are some examples on how to switch title layout only.

Answer (score -1):

You can't do it. You must use a activity and set its theme to dialog. like this

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
```

when you start your activity it's start as a dialog and setTypeFace in your xml layout file or set it programmatically. If you don't want to have a Title set this code :

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

It'll need to be done immediately after calling super.onCreate.